# Grinding feeling on newish motorcycle brakes and rotors

Tags: motorcycle, brakes, brake-rotor

I got my Kawasaki W800's brake pads and rotor replaced (single, front disc), with Kawasaki parts from a a Kawasaki dealer. Everything felt fine for the first 1,000 km but now (1200 km) it feels very 'grindy' - I can feel slight vibrations at low speed.

Appearance wise, the rotor seems fine.

Anything to be worried about?

Comment: Throw some WD-40 on it! :o) J/K!

Answer (score 2):

If the vibrations are there only when you apply the brakes then perhaps the rotor has suffered some overheating from a sticking/binding caliper .

If you do your own work.. Just remove the caliper and pads and check that the calipers piston is able to compress back into the caliper body reasonably easily. If not, pumping it up slightly with the brake lever (NOT too much) and re-compressing it a few times should free it up.

Also you could buy a cheap dial test indicator or borrow one just to check the discs runout. If the disc is running straight then the vibration is originating somewhere else.. Perhaps the front tyre.